# Create a pair / set of tuples and delete certain elements

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to create a set of tuples and then modify it.

Input:

```
r = np.float64([0, 0, 1, 1])

z = np.float64([[2,6],[3,7],[4,8],[5,9]])
```

Now to pair r to z:

```
r[0] = 0 to z[0] = array([2, 6])
```

Same with r[1], r[2], r[3] ...

In the last step to remove all pairs which contain a 0 as former r entry.

Output:

```
p = [[[1 , [4,8]],[1 , [5,9]]]
```

and separated:

```
p1 = [1 , 1]
p2 = [[4,8],[5,9]]
```

I have tried to create the set with:

```
t = r , z
```

And then to use filter:

```
tp = list(filter(lambda num : num !=0, t[0]))
```

But the output is just the cuted r without the corresponding z values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p = [x for x in zip(r, z) if x[0] != 0]
p1 = [x[0] for x in p]
p2 = [x[1] for x in p]
```